# Will Raspberry Pi 4b be able to use Intel Optane p1600x NVME without crashing?

Tags: pi-4

I am wondering if anybody know by experience if RPi 4 would be able to handle p1600x intel Optane nvme.

I know that NVMEs are power hungry and their speed is an overkill for a single shared 4Gb/s USB bus of RPi 4, but Optane is relatively cheap and has a huge advantage of ultra-low latency and ultra-high IOPs that even RPi could take advantage of—-especially in applications such as data bases and web hosting.

According to my calculations, RPi’s usb port should have just barely enough power to carry p1600x optane module, but data safety is important, and I was wondering if anyone tried it and experienced any crashes or data corruption due to not enough power; or if the CPU was undervolt-throttling itself as RPi’s do when they sense undervoltage.

I was thinking about using a 3-Ampere USB-C charger from iPad, which is more powerful than the official RPi one. If an even more powerful charger would help to carry the Optane, that would be great.